# DRF/django-filter programmatically calling a Filterset class without using the Viewset/request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-filter

I am building functionality to allow users to save a set of filters from a query-builder component on my Angular frontend. I am also using the django-filter package to power most of the search ability in my app.

Say I have a model named MyModel (with a FK field 'category') and a ViewsSet wherein I've specified filterset_class = MyModeFilter

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class MyModelFilter(filters.Filterset):

    category_in = filters.BaseCSVFilter(field_name='category', method='filter_category_in')
    
    def filter_category_in(self, qs, name, value):
        # filters happen
        return qs
```

This works well when my frontend calls https://api-url/mymodel/?category_in=1,2,3

What I want to do now is programmatically call this filter from inside the django app.

Use case: I need to program a CRON job to build and email an excel report based on a queryset that would match the [?category_in=1,2,3](https://api-url/mymodel/?category_in=1,2,3) param filter. This is very straightforward with the ViewSets when using DRF requests, but I don't know where to start looking at his to use this filter without going the requests route.

The the filter is saved in a JSONField (saved_query_statement) in a model called SavedQuery. It will look something like this:

```
sqs = {
    'name': 'category',
    'lookup_expr': 'in',
    'value': '1,2,3'
}
```

So the CRON job function, when executed, will do a SavedQuery.objects.get() call and get the query which is relevant to it, then it needs to get the MyModel queryset where (category__in=[1,2,3])
How can I take the JSON/string representation of this filter without doing a lot of something like this (I have over 50 possible filters with more to come...)

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
if 'category' in sqs.get('name'):
    if 'in' in sqs.get('lookup_expr'):
        ids = [int(v) for v in sqs.get('value').split(',')]
        qs.filter(category__in=ids)

...
```

TLDR, I'd like to use the django-filter Filterset class without going through the Viewset... any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `**` to unpack filter key/value args and make it somewhat generic:

```
qs.filter(**kv)
```

In your case, it would go something like this:

```py
qs = MyModel.objects.all()

# Somehow create kwargs from your JSON
filter_key = sqs.get('name')
lookup_expr = sqs.get('lookup_expr')
if lookup_expr:
    filter_key += '__{}'.format(lookup_expr)
filter_value = parse_filter_value(sqs.get('value'))  # This is a bit tricky
kwargs = {filter_key: filter_value}

# Now filter
qs.filter(**kwargs)
```

You'll have to figure out how to implement `parse_filter_value`, but that's not the core problem here, and in general this approach can be very handy.